# How to open consecutive dialogs

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, dialog-window

I am new using mathematica so I would really appreciate your help. 
I want to open this dialog:

```
CreateDialog[Column[{"Type A and B",Grid[{{"A:",InputField[Dynamic[A],Number]},{"B:",InputField[Dynamic[B],Number]},{CancelButton[],DefaultButton[]}},Spacings->{1,Automatic},Alignment->Left]}],Modal->True]
```

And after the user types A and B, I want to open this one:

```
Grid1={{"Item","Info","-"}};
For[i=1,i<=A,i++,AppendTo[Grid1,{"A" <> ToString[i],InputField[],Checkbox[]}]]
CreateDialog[Column[{Grid[Grid1],Row[{CancelButton[],DefaultButton[]}]}],Modal->True]
```

And then a third one and so on, the problem is, these dialogs open simultaneously, and I want the second one to open after ok or cancel button is pressed in the first one, and so on. How can I achieve this?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try `DialogInput` rather than `CreateDialog`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!